# AVL Search Tree having problem with either insert or balance or rotations

Tags: java, avl-tree

I am creating my own implementation of an AVL search tree. I have done a basic binary search tree and had no problems with it at all. I am using my basic binary tree code as a starting point for the AVL tree. When I test it, it comes up with a Null Pointer Exception. Now, I do understand what that means, and in the past I have been able locate and fix this sort of problem. However, I can't seem to determine exactly where the problem is, or how to fix it. I feel I could be overlooking something pretty simple. As sometimes we are too close to our own projects.

I believe I have narrowed down the problem to just a few possible sections of code that is causing the problem. I have included that code here. If anyone feels they need to see more code, please let me know and I will post more. I have narrowed down the problem so it seems to only appear when inserting. Since the insert method also calls the balance method, which in turn calls the rotation methods, the problem is quite possibly in one of those areas. I also feel that the problem is related to either the balance or rotation methods, as the insert method is almost the same I am using on the basic binary search tree, which works fine. I feel that I should be able to find where this is coming from, just getting tired and frustrated, so I thought it would be time to ask for help.

Here are the related methods, if you need to see more, let me know.

```
// Insert item into tree
// Duplicates are ignored
// Pre: Accept item x, that represents item to insert
public void insert(E x) {
    root = insert(x, root);
}

// Internal method to insert item into tree
// Pre: Accept item x, that represent item to insert
// Pre: Accept AVL Node t, that represents roots of the subtree
// Post: Return AVL Node, representing new root of tree
private AvlNode<E> insert(E x, AvlNode<E> t) {
    if (t == null) {
        return new AvlNode<>(x, null, null);
    }

    int compareResult = x.compareTo(t.item);

    if (compareResult < 0) {
        t.leftChild = insert(x, t.leftChild);
    } else if (compareResult > 0) {
        t.rightChild = insert(x, t.rightChild);
    } else {
        ;   // Duplicate do nothing
    }
    return balance(t);
}

// Balances the tree
// Assume t is either balanced or within one of being balanced
// Pre: Accept AVL Node t, representing roots of tree
// Post: Return AVL Node
private AvlNode<E> balance(AvlNode<E> t) {
    if (t == null) {
        return t;
    }

    if (height(t.leftChild) - height(t.rightChild) > IMBALANCE_ALLOWED) {
        if (height(t.leftChild.leftChild) >= height(t.leftChild.rightChild)) {
            t = rotateWithLefChild(t);
        } else {
            t = doubleWithLeftChild(t);
        }
    } else {
        if (height(t.rightChild) - height(t.leftChild) > IMBALANCE_ALLOWED) {
            if (height(t.rightChild.rightChild) >= height(t.rightChild.leftChild)) {
                t = rotateWithRightChild(t);
            }
        } else {
            t = doubleWithRightChild(t);
        }
    }
    t.height = Math.max(height(t.leftChild), height(t.rightChild)) + 1;
    return t;
}

// Rotate tree node with left child
// Single rotation
// Updates height
// Pre: accept AVL Node
// Post: Return AVL Node, this node represents new root
private AvlNode<E> rotateWithLefChild(AvlNode<E> k2) {
    AvlNode<E> k1 = k2.leftChild;
    k2.leftChild = k1.rightChild;
    k1.rightChild = k2;
    k2.height = Math.max(height(k2.leftChild), height(k2.rightChild)) + 1;
    k1.height = Math.max(height(k1.leftChild), k2.height) + 1;
    return k1;
}

// Rotate tree node with right child
// Single rotation
// Updates height
// Pre: Accept AVL Node
// Post: Return AVL Node, this node represents new root
private AvlNode<E> rotateWithRightChild(AvlNode<E> k1) {
    AvlNode<E> k2 = k1.rightChild;
    k1.rightChild = k2.leftChild;
    k2.leftChild = k1;
    k1.height = Math.max(height(k1.leftChild), height(k1.rightChild)) + 1;
    k2.height = Math.max(height(k2.rightChild), k1.height) + 1;
    return k2;
}

// Double rotate tree node, first left child with its right child, then node k3 with new left child
// Double rotation
// Updates height
// Pre: Accept AVL Node
// Post: Return AVL Node, this node represents new root
private AvlNode<E> doubleWithLeftChild(AvlNode<E> k3) {
    k3.leftChild = rotateWithRightChild(k3.leftChild);
    return rotateWithLefChild(k3);
}

// Double rotate tree node, first right child with its left child then node k1with new right child
// Double rotation
// Updates height
// Pre: Accept AVL Node
// Post: Return AVL Node, this node represents new root
private AvlNode<E> doubleWithRightChild(AvlNode<E> k1) {
    k1.rightChild = rotateWithLefChild(k1.rightChild);
    return rotateWithRightChild(k1);

}
```

During my debugging process, my compiler showed that the following lines could be where the problem is:
In the public insert method:

```
    root = insert(x, root);
```

In the private insert method:

```
   return balance(t);
```

In the balance method:

```
   t = doubleWithRightChild(t);
```

In the rotateWithLeftChild method:

```
   k2.leftChild = k1.rightChild;
```

And finally the doubleWithRightChild method:

```
   k1.rightChild = rotateWithLefChild(k1.rightChild);
```

These are the lines marked by the compiler (not that, that always shows where the problem is).

After further debugging I seemed to have located the place that throws the exception. It appears to happen as soon as the code enters the private insert method:

```
    private AvlNode<E> insert(E x, AvlNode<E> t) {
            if (t == null) {
        return new AvlNode<>(x, null, null);
            }
```

It seems to be right here that the exception gets thrown. So now I am thinking it could be my constructor or something. However, in my basic binary tree, the constructor is exactly the same, and there is no problem with that code. My constructor is pretty basic, and like I said the exact same as with my properly functioning basic binary tree.

```
    // Constructor
        public MyAVLTree() {
            root = null;
        }
```

So any thoughts or suggestions. Thank you for your time and assistance.

After doing a bit more testing, I have discovered that this exception is only thrown when one more one value is inserted. If their is only one value added, then there is no error.

So, now I am thinking it has something to do with how I am linking nodes?

Comment: The stacktrace of the exception will tell you the line where the explosion happened. From there you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Yea, I think that point is when the code enters the private insert method, in the if(t==null) statement. The thing that I don't understand, is this is the exact same code I have used in a working basic binary search tree. So I am not sure why this would trigger an exception, or how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have figured out what the problem was. I had some of my brackets {} screwed up and in the wrong places in the balance method. For those who are interested, this is how it should be.

```
// Balances the tree
// Assume t is either balanced or within one of being balanced
// Pre: Accept AVL Node t, representing roots of tree
// Post: Return AVL Node
private AvlNode<E> balance(AvlNode<E> t) {
    if (t == null) {
        return t;
    }

    if (height(t.leftChild) - height(t.rightChild) > IMBALANCE_ALLOWED) {
        if (height(t.leftChild.leftChild) >= height(t.leftChild.rightChild)) {
            t = rotateWithLefChild(t);
        }
        else {
            t = doubleWithLeftChild(t);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (height(t.rightChild) - height(t.leftChild) > IMBALANCE_ALLOWED) {
            if (height(t.rightChild.rightChild) >= height(t.rightChild.leftChild)) {
                t = rotateWithRightChild(t);
        }
        else {
            t = doubleWithRightChild(t);
        }
    }
}
    t.height = Math.max(height(t.leftChild), height(t.rightChild)) + 1;
    return t;
}
```

Thank you for your time